# Blender Online Product Configurator - Dynamicly Updates Geometry

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blend4web

Is it possible to make an online product configurator using Blender Cycles rendered models that dynamically stretch and grow?

As user enters their custom dimensions (height and width) could their product's 3D model update to that size in real time?

Bonus: could objects be added as the product gets bigger?

Like a ladder that could be any custom length, but for every extra 12" it adds another rung.  Then re-spaces all rungs equally apart.

Couldn't find any configurators like this.  Usually they only change color and swap parts.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723471/three-js-scale-model-with-scale-set-or-increase-model-size

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Blend4Web offers JavaScript API which you can use to modify the geometry in run-time.

Additional objects can be added too.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this, which I could show to the client?  That would help convince them to use this tool.  Otherwise they plan to use only 2D images for product configurator.  Thanks.

Comment: https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/furniture_3D_configurator/
https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/3d_ring_boutique/

Comment: Thank you, very nice examples.  With the furniture example, it has pre-set dimensions to choose from.  Do you have any examples where the user can type in their own special dimensions and see it update the model to any size they want?